# Generic way to implement a Pk Writes in Play Scala

Tags: scala, generics, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to write a generic way of handling the writing of the `Pk` class to JSON in Play 2.1, as I think it's wasteful to write a separate one for every `Pk` type you are using.  Here's what I have so far:

```
implicit def pkWrites[E] = new Writes[Pk[E]] {
    def writes(pk: Pk[E]): JsValue = Json.toJson(pk.get)
}
```

...and I use it in code like this:

```
Json.toJson(Id(42L))
```

Now, this sort of works (Scala finds it) but here's the error I get:

```
No Json deserializer found for type E. 
Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
```

Where type `E` is `Long` (and thus, has a deserializer).  Is there anyway I can tell `Json.toJson` what type `E` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is ensuring that there is deserializer for type `E` in scope, because now you can't be sure that each type you use is writeable. You can try it:

```
class Value[A](value: A){
  def get[A] = value
}

implicit def valueWrites[E](implicit longWrites: Writes[E]) = new Writes[Value[E]]{
    def writes(value: Value[E]): JsValue = Json.toJson(value.get)
}

Json.toJson(new Value(5L))
```

You can shorten implicit method to:

```
implicit def valueToJson[E: Writes] = new Writes[Value[E]]{
    def writes(value: Value[E]): JsValue = Json.toJson(value.get)
}
```

Edit:

These two methods above are exactly the same, it means that method needs implicit value, in your case `Pk[Long]`, so this method knows how to deserialize number. In other words, `E: Writes` tells the method: search for implicit value of type `Writes[E]`.

Edit 2:

`Json.toJson(1)` works because there is `Writes[Int]` in scope. In the same way works `valueWrites[Int]`, there is `Writes[Int]` in scope, so method can use `Writes[Int]` to deserialize field `value` and, hence deserialize entire class.

Comment: Ok, so all I did was add `E: Writes` to the `pkWrites` type parameter and it works... what does `:` mean in type parameter? I'm very new to Scala.

Comment: So `E: Writes` is shorthand for saying make sure `E` is implicitly convertible to `Writes`?

Comment: Almost. It's shorthand for "There is Writes[E] or in your case Writes[Long] in scope"